# Finding files/folders deleted from truecrypt container

Tags: truecrypt, data-recovery

In the course of "backing up" my TrueCrypt files,  I managed to delete the wrong files (deleting my new files and and leaving the older backups instead). I tried pressing Ctrl-Z but no luck. I have also tried running Recuva, but it only seems to find random old files that were deleted and none of the hundreds of recently-deleted files. I understand that the files should have gone to a recycle bin, but I nothing appears to be there.

Is there a way to find/recover these deleted folders/files?

Further background: The truecrypt container is on a flash drive (not my boot drive).

Answer (score 0):

If your TrueCrypt filesystem is FAT32, and if the files were deleted rather than securely erased, and if you haven't written to the TrueCrypt container, you may be able to recover them using an undeletion utility.  (If your TrueCrypt container is using some other filesystem (eg. NTFS), you can try recovering the files using an undeletion utility, but it's less likely to succeed.)